# How to track subtitles and audio change in AVPlayerItem?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avfoundation

I have an AVPlayerItem and I subscribed to some observers to track changes. But I need to track when user changes audio track or subtitles from video. How can I do this? Is this even possible with system player? Or I need to make a custom overlay with controls?

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I've founded in documentation a notification called [AVPlayerItemMediaSelectionDidChangeNotification](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avplayeritemmediaselectiondidchangenotification?language=objc), but this works only from iOS 13.

```
    if (@available(iOS 13.0, *)) {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(handleMediaSelectionChange:)
                                                 name:AVPlayerItemMediaSelectionDidChangeNotification
                                               object:playerItem];
}
```

Comment: The notification `AVPlayerItemMediaSelectionDidChangeNotification` appeared in the public API on iOS 13 but internally it was available since much earlier (at least iOS 10.3 as far as I can tell), so you could also add an observer for `@"AVPlayerItemMediaSelectionDidChangeNotification"` instead and it should work ;)